# DRM WideVine video not playing from android cast sender application

Tags: android, chromecast, widevine, custom-receiver

I am using the following **cast receiver**

When I connect my android sender to chromecast device, it show a black screen and never plays video.

https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer

I'm setting **licenseUrl** for **widevine** in receiver as follow:

```
sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.preloadVideo_ = function(mediaInformation) {
  this.log_('preloadVideo_');
  var self = this;
  var url = mediaInformation.contentId;
  var protocolFunc = sampleplayer.getProtocolFunction_(mediaInformation);
  if (!protocolFunc) {
    this.log_('No protocol found for preload');
    return false;
  }
  var host = new cast.player.api.Host({
    'url': url,
    'mediaElement': self.mediaElement_
  });
  host.onError = function() {
    self.preloadPlayer_.unload();
    self.preloadPlayer_ = null;
    self.showPreviewModeMetadata(false);
    self.displayPreviewMode_ = false;
    self.log_('Error during preload');
  };
      host.licenseUrl = event.data.customData.licenseUrl;
      self.preloadPlayer_ = new cast.player.api.Player(host);
      self.preloadPlayer_.preload(protocolFunc(host));
      return true;
    };
```

> host.licenseUrl = event.data.customData.licenseUrl;

I've hosted it on a https server which is registered on developers console.

I'm passing custom data as **licenseUrl** in a json object.

The code of my android sender setting **media info** is below.

```
private MediaInfo buildMediaInfo() {
        MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
        movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Subtitle");
        movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Title");
        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonObj.put("licenseUrl","https://wv.test.expressplay.com/hms/wv/rights/?ExpressPlayToken=token-value");
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e(null,"Failed to add description to the json object", e);
        }
        /*drmModel.getData().getStreamURL()*/
        return new MediaInfo.Builder("https://pathOfMystream.mpd")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("application/dash+xml")
                .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                .setCustomData(jsonObj)
                .setStreamDuration(player.getDuration()*1000)
                .build();
    }
```

- What changes are further required ?
- Do I need to edit receiver? If yes, then what edits are needed?
- Is the string name in **customData** **"licenseUrl"** needs to be
  changed?
- **CORS is enabled** on the S3 server which is hosting the video contents.

Please help! I'm stuck here for more than a week.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out that `event.data.customData` was undefined while connecting from android sender application.

So I used `event.data.media.customData`

And accessed the **key** as follow:

```
if(event.data.media.customData['licenseUrl'] !== null){
                    console.log('setting license URL from mobile');
                    host.licenseUrl = event.data.media.customData.licenseUrl;
                }
```